# NGINX does not pass POST request when posted to /

Tags: php, nginx

The issue occurs when sending a post request `{username:'admin', password: 'password'}` to `http://guy.lt/fbb?foo=bar`. The output is `{"foo":"bar"}`, though the expected output is: `{"foo":"bar","username":"admin","password":"password"}`. (PHP backend outputs JSON encoded `$_REQUEST`) However, if I send POST request directly to `http://guy.lt/fbb/index.php?foo=bar`, I get the expected output.

All the relevant config:

```
https://gist.github.com/98f4e8fc56d1d2d706fd nginx.conf
https://gist.github.com/f9a60f3914696dca3374 anuary_standard_server
https://gist.github.com/6300bb66620d3731d776 virtualhosts.conf
https://gist.github.com/789ad2b0645cade2f9dc anuary_location_php
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/271149/put-to-static-file-in-nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NginX cannot POST to a static file (url without a files extension)

You need to change the POST into a GET by proxying to self.

See this gist for relevant components of my solution: https://gist.github.com/1021739

More info may be found here:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.nginx.english/1941/match=post+405+static

Hope this help